# Does there exist a function such that the preimage of $x ^ { 2 } + y ^ { 2 } \leq 1$ is the closed interval $[-1,1]?$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Does there exist a continuous function $f : \mathbb { R } \rightarrow \mathbb { R } ^ { 2 }$ such
that the preimage of the closed unit disk $x ^ { 2 } + y ^ { 2 } \leq 1$ is the closed
interval $[ - 1,1 ] ?$ the open interval $( - 1,1 ) ?$

To be honest, I don't really know how to go about this problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can get a continuous function from $[-1,1]$ to the closed unit disc by an appropriate space filling curve.

Comment: the preimage of a set $S$ being $[-1,1]$ is not the same thing as the image of $[-1,1]$ being $S$.  space filling curves are super overkill

Comment: @RolfHoyer how would you go about this without using space filling functions? We never went over those in my lecture so I doubt the answer would have to be related to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Space filling curves certainly work but that's quite excessive.

For a function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$ defined by $f(x):=(f_1(x),f_2(x))$, the preimage of $D:=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:x^2+y^2\le 1 \}$ is merely the set 
$$\begin{align}
f^{-1}(D) &= \{ x\in\Bbb R: (f_1(x),f_2(x))\in D \} \\
&= \{ x\in\Bbb R: f_1(x)^2+f_2(x)^2\le 1 \}.
\end{align}$$

By letting $f(x)=(x,0)$, we have
$$
f^{-1}(D)= \{ x\in\Bbb R: x^2\le 1 \} = [-1,1].
$$

On the other hand, by requiring that $f$ be continuous, the preimage of $D$, which is a closed set, must also be closed. Since $(-1,1)$ is not closed, we cannot find a continuous function such that $f^{-1}(D)=(-1,1)$.

Comment: Yep. The trick here is to realize that the preimage need not necessarily give the given set when the function is then applied to it - only that the result of such application be contained within the given set.

Answer (score 1):

f:R -> R×R, x -> (x,0) is continuous.
Let D be the closed unit disk.
The preimage of D by f is
f$^{-1}$(D) = { x : f(x) in D } = [-1,1].

Comment: Good example, but you really should format it better.